# Cognito Forms filtering concatenated values from a repeating section

Tags: cognitoforms

I have been successful in concatenating all emails from a repeatingSection in Cognito Forms but I want to filter which items are included based on another field in the repeatingSection.

NotificationList.Select(Email) - this work great. But I want to only include items where item.status = toplevelfield.status as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using a work around as follows:

1. Add a calculation field  RepeatingSection.ParentStatus = Status (toplevel field)
2. Add a calculation field RepeatingSection.NotifyEmailCalc =ParentStatus.Contains(NotifyStatus) - this boolean is used to filter the Email list in next step
3. at a toplevel calculation field - Emails=NotificationList.Where(NotifyEmailCalc = true).Select(Email)
4. toplevel calculation fields "Email" = "Emails"
5. InsertField 'Email' into the Update Workflow To:email in the template